# How to retrieve or iterate over edge keys in python networkx MultiDiGraph

Tags: python, key, networkx

I have a `MultiDiGraph`, in which there may exist multiple edges between nodes that are differentiated based on a key. Across the graph I have many keys and I'd like to iterate over them, performing a task for each key.

One way I could deal with this is to iterate over all edges, and store the keys in a set. Then I'll be able to iterate over the elements of that set:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_edge('a', 'b', 1)
G.add_edge('a', 'b', 2)
G.add_edge('b', 'c', 1)
G.add_edge('c', 'a', 3)

# Iterate over edges in the map and store the keys
keys = set(e[2] for e in G.edges_iter(keys=True))

# Now do something for each key
for key in keys:
    pass # do something
```

But this seems awfully inefficient, as I'll ultimately be iterating over the edges of `G`, and then again back over `keys`.

I understand that I can make this more efficient by building my set along the way:

```
keys = set()
for e in G.edges_iter(keys=True):
    key = e[2]
    if key in keys:
        continue

    keys.add(key)
    # do something
```

But I'm really hoping there's something special in `networkx` I just haven't come across, or some idiom to make this neat. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

NetworkX stores the keys in the adjacency structure so the only way to access them is by iterating over data

This seems like the best way

```
# Iterate over edges in the map and store the keys
keys = set(e[2] for e in G.edges_iter(keys=True))
```

unless you can the keys as you add the edges. You could subclass the `add_edge` method to store the keys in an separate data structure as you add them.