# Retrieving partial keys 'key for key in part...' - Networkx

Tags: python, networkx, matplotlib-basemap

I'm attempting this tutorial: ["Networks on Maps (with Python)"](http://www.sociology-hacks.org/?p=67). With the kind help of the original author, I've got most of it working. It was originally created in Python 2.7, and I'm using 3.5. Changes include data in graphml format (not pickle), inserting a missing argument, and specifying G=nx.Graph().

I'm stuck now towards the end with error:

```
NameError: name 'part' is not defined.
```

I'm a little unsure if it's a 2.7-3.5 conflict, of if there's a function missing?

Here's the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import difflib

m = Basemap(projection='robin',lon_0=0,resolution='l')

m.drawcountries(linewidth = 0.5)
m.fillcontinents(color='white',lake_color='white')
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5)

# load geographic coordinate system for countries
import csv
country = [row[0].strip() for row in csv.reader(open('LonLat.csv'), delimiter=';')]    # clear spaces
lat = [float(row[1]) for row in csv.reader(open('LonLat.csv'), delimiter=';')]
lon = [float(row[2]) for row in csv.reader(open('LonLat.csv'), delimiter=';')]

G=nx.Graph()

# define position in basemap
    position = {}
    for i in range(0, len(country)):
        position[country[i]] = m(lon[i], lat[i])

    def similar(landstring, country):
        l = difflib.get_close_matches(landstring, country, 1)
        return l[0]

    pos = dict((land, position[similar(land, country)]) for land in G.nodes())

    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist = [**key for key in part if part[key] == 0**],
         node_size = [deg_weight[s]*10 for s in part if part[s] == 0],
         node_color = 'red', node_shape='^', alpha=0.8)
         nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist = [key for key in part if part[key] == 1],
         node_size = [deg_weight[s]*20 for s in part if part[s] == 1],
         node_color = 'black', node_shape='d')
         nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist = [key for key in part if part[key] == 2],
         node_size = [deg_weight[s]*10 for s in part if part[s] == 2],
         node_color = 'green', node_shape='o')
         nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist = [key for key in part if part[key] == 3],
         node_size = [deg_weight[s]*10 for s in part if part[s] == 3],
         node_color = 'blue', alpha=0.8)
         nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, color='grey', width = 0.75, alpha=0.2)
         plt.show()
```

It feels like this answer ([How to retrieve or iterate over edge keys in python networkx MultiDiGraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36409438/how-to-retrieve-or-iterate-over-edge-keys-in-python-networkx-multidigraph)), this answer ([Python Tulpe Key For Dict Partial Lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017943/python-tulpe-key-for-dict-partial-lookup)), and this answer ([How to access keys in nodes and edges in NetworkX MultiDiGraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016087/how-to-access-keys-in-nodes-and-edges-in-networkx-multidigraph)) are pointing in the right direction, but I can't make enough of a link.

Any input would be much appreciated. I'd love to get it fully working.

Comment: Is this a typo, should `part` instead be `pos`?  You're getting the Name Error because there is no `part` assigned anywhere in this code.

Comment: It could well be. I replaced all 'part' with 'pos' earlier but it didn't work. I'll try again since you bring it up.

Comment: At the very least, that shouldn't give you a `NameError`, but it might fail for some other reasons. I looked briefly at the example you provided, and I see similar disconnect where there is no mention of `part` until these list comprehensions.

Comment: Thanks. This is the full traceback error:
`NameError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f58d009eb708> in <module>()
33 pos = dict((land, position[similar(land, country)]) for land in G.nodes())
34 
---> 35 nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist = [key for key in part if part[key] == 0],
36 node_size = [deg_weight[s]*10 for s in part if part[s] == 0],
37 node_color = 'red', node_shape='^', alpha=0.8)
NameError: name 'part' is not defined`

Comment: I put the rest of the code in since it's not very long.

Comment: You're still using `part` instead of `pos`. Or, change `pos` to `part` if that is easier. You can't call on a variable if it hasn't been previously defined. `part` is simply not defined anywhere in your code. That's what `NameError: name 'part' is not defined'` means.

Comment: Thanks. I get that. This is just the original code.

Comment: Right, so what happens if you correct for what appears to be an obvious error in the source code?

Comment: Just tried it again. It returns a blank map of the world with coastlines and country borders, but no nodes or edges.

Comment: That's about as much help as I can offer, solved your `NameError`, but as for the specific implementation of this, it's not something that I'm at all familiar with.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look anyway.

Comment: TBH it looks like something is missing in the example where you got this code. I would expect the same error, unless there is additional code which he didn't provide, which assigns to the `part` object.

Comment: Just heard back from the author. Seems I need the community API (http://perso.crans.org/aynaud/communities/api.html) to detect communities. This step wasn't in the original blog post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code worked nearly completely. A couple of small issues remain, e.g. the map appears "above" the edges and nodes, 'deg_weight' not defined, but it mostly works. Will post if I get around to fixing fully. Posting here for anyone who's interested. Thanks to Dr. Raphael Heiberger for generous assistance.

```
#import sys
#sys.version
#'3.5.1 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)...

# import modules
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import csv
import difflib
import community # https://bitbucket.org/taynaud/python-louvain

# define map
m = Basemap(projection='robin',lon_0=0,resolution='l')
m.drawcountries(linewidth = 0.5)
m.fillcontinents(color='white',lake_color='white')
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5)

# load geographic coordinates for countries
country = [row[0].strip() for row in csv.reader(open('LonLat.csv'), delimiter=';')]    # clear spaces
lat = [float(row[1]) for row in csv.reader(open('LonLat.csv'), delimiter=';')]
lon = [float(row[2]) for row in csv.reader(open('LonLat.csv'), delimiter=';')]

# load data
G = nx.read_graphml('data.graphml')

# define position in basemap
position = {} 
for i in range(0, len(country)): 
    position[country[i]] = m(lon[i], lat[i])

def similar(landstring, country):
    l = difflib.get_close_matches(landstring, country, 1)
    return l[0]

pos = dict((land, position[similar(land, country)]) for land in G.nodes())

part = community.best_partition(G)

# draw graph
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist = [key for key in part if part[key] == 0], 
                       node_size = [deg_weight[s]*10 for s in part if part[s] == 0], 
                       node_color = 'red', node_shape='^', alpha=0.8)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist = [key for key in part if part[key] == 1], 
                       node_size = [deg_weight[s]*20 for s in part if part[s] == 1],
                       node_color = 'black', node_shape='d')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist = [key for key in part if part[key] == 2],
                       node_size = [deg_weight[s]*10 for s in part if part[s] == 2],
                       node_color = 'green', node_shape='o')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist = [key for key in part if part[key] == 3],
                       node_size = [deg_weight[s]*10 for s in part if part[s] == 3],
                       node_color = 'blue', alpha=0.8)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, color='grey', width = 0.75, alpha=0.2)

#print/generate plot
plt.show()
```